# Vim dynamic linked dependency not listed via ldd

Tags: vim, ldd

Install vim from source successfully

```
$ git clone https://github.com/vim/vim && cd vim
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gui=no --enable-python3interp=dynamic
$ make CFLAGS='-O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1'
$ sudo make install
```

Test the plugin in `python3` successfully

```
python3 << EOF
print("Hello, Python3!")
EOF
```

Check if `python3` dynamically linked

```
$ /usr/local/bin/vim --version
+python3/dyna
$ ll -h /usr/local/bin/vim
2.6M
$ ldconfig -p | grep python3
libpython3
$ ldd /usr/local/bin/vim | grep python
(nothing)
```

Something `libpython3` should have been listed, why does nothing show up here?

Comment: You try following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47133334/11384392)?

Comment: @Das_Geek That won't help if python isn't even in the list of shared library dependencies.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Right, duh. Don't know where my head was at with that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `dynamic` the library is not linked, it is loaded by the vim binary on the first use, using `dlopen()`. From `:help python-dynamic`:

> On MS-Windows and Unix the Python library can be loaded dynamically.  The
>   :version output then includes +python/dyn or +python3/dyn.
>
> This means that Vim will search for the Python DLL or shared library file only
>   when needed.  When you don't use the Python interface you don't need it, thus
>   you can use Vim without this file.
>
> ...
>
> The 'pythondll' or 'pythonthreedll' option can be used to specify the Python
>   shared library file ...

and `:help 'pythonthreedll'`:

> Specifies the name of the Python 3 shared library. The default is
>   DYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL, which was specified at compile time.